# WebPack Babel ignore node_modules with exceptions

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I have a node_module that is written in ES6 so causes issues when trying to view this in IE11.  To solve this I setup `babel` so which solves the issue with IE11.  But, babel seems to be trying to parse ALL node modules rather than just the one I want it to.  How do I properly exclude all node modules bar `flv.js`? Note I found the exclusion syntax from this [github thread](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/171)

```
{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude:/node_modules\/(?!flv.js)/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
        presets: ['es2015']
    }
},
```

WebPack output that makes me think its transpiling more than just `flv.js`

> [BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of
> "C:/TFS/.../node_modules/lodash/lodash.js"
> as it exceeds the max of "500KB".
>
> [BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of
> "C:/TFS/.../node_modules/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.js"
> as it exceeds the max of "500KB".
>
> [BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of
> "C:/TFS/.../node_modules/angular/angular.js"
> as it exceeds the max of "500KB".
>
> [BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of
> "C:/TFS/...b/node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js"
> as it exceeds the max of "500KB".

Comment: That is the entire name of the file you wish to include? And does it in turn import eg lodash?

Comment: Did you figure out what was going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this, but the only way I managed was to transpile the node module using babel, like so (WebPack 3).  Note for speed I ignore all node modules bar the offending one (flv.js)

```
{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules\/(?!flv.js)/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
        presets: ['es2015'],
        compact: true
    }
},
```

Add the following to package.json

```
"babel-core": "6.23.0",
"babel-loader": "7.1.4",
"babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
"babel-preset-env": "1.6.1",
```